# WordPress For Urdu Language

Tags: multi-language, translation

Can I use WordPress for Urdu Language?
I want entire site to be toggled-translated in Urdu Language with one click...
Is it possible to do it with some plugin or do i have to write manual codes for every component?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress is community translated. For a good number of languages, the translation is relatively complete and follows high quality standards.

The codex page on [WordPress in your language](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language) reports:

> WordPress in Urdu - اردو is ongoing, but slow. Need more contributors.

So in essence: No, WP is not entirely translated to Urdu yet. You could contribute though and push things forward, if you cared.

WP uses gettext, so the translation process itself is pretty straightforward. See [I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers), if you want to find out more.

Answer (score 0):

> In the past few versions of WordPress, I have been leading the effort to help make WordPress 100% translated in Urdu. Along with me is my team of devs especially Saqib Ameen — who's done an incredible job managing the translations.

I'm going to drop a few resources here for you to get WordPress in Urdu!

- https://UR.WordPress.org/.
- [Learn how to translate WordPress in Urdu](https://wpcouple.com/how-to-translate-wordpress-in-urdu/)
- [Build Your Next Multilingual Site in Minutes with TranslatePress](https://wpcouple.com/translatepress-build-next-multilingual-site-minutes/)
- Join us on a [Global Translation Day](https://wpcouple.com/meetup-global-wordpress-translation-day-3/) next time.